# XML file data is lost when sudden shutdown is occurred

Tags: c#, shutdown, xelement

I have an application that stores data in XML file every 500 ms using XElement object's .Save("path") method.
The problem is : when a sudden shutdown is occurred the content of the file is deleted so on the next run of the application the file can not be used.

How to prevent that / make sure the data will not be lost?
P.S:  I'm using .NET 2010 C# under windows 7

I've made an experiment: instead of writing to the same data.xml file I've created (by copying from the original file) a new file each time and when the power was off while copying from data.xml file it would corrupt all previously created files?!?!?

Comment: You would need to have the concept of a business transaction, such that you started the process over from the last good checkpoint in the case of a shutdown. You need to rephrase your question to include more detail. In general, the file system is not transactional.

Comment: What kind of infrastructure are you dealing with where there's a sudden shutdown? You mean like a loss of power? Do you not have a battery backup for something like this??

Comment: Tanks for the answers/comments - I don't have a backup battery and this is a rare situation that has to be treated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's assume your file is `data.xml`. Instead of writing to `data.xml` all the time, write to a temporary file `data.xml.tmp`, and when finished, rename it to `data.xml`. But renaming will not work if you already have a `data.xml` file, so you will need to delete it first and then rename the temporary file.

That way, `data.xml` will contain the last safe data. If you have a sudden shutdown, the incomplete file will be the temporary `data.xml.tmp`. If your program tries to read the file later on and there is no `data.xml` file, that means the shutdown happened between the delete and rename operations, so you will have to read the temporary file instead. We know it is safe because otherwise there would be a `data.xml` file.

Comment: You can not rename `data.xml.tmp` to `data.xml` while `data.xml` exists. can you clarify in which step you delete the `data.xml`

Comment: Suppose you have `data.xml` and `data.xml.tmp` after a shutdown. How do you know `data.xml.tmp` is written completely or not? Crash might have occured before or after finishing to write `data.xml.tmp`

Comment: @I4V if you have both, the correct one is always `data.xml`. If the crash happens when renaming, then `data.xml.tmp` is good too, but you cannot be sure

Comment: Julián, `if you have both, the correct one is always data.xml` Absolutely No.  keyword here is `but you cannot be sure`. So You will never know which one is "the most recently updated and also correct" file.

Comment: Good Lord, I meant "the one you have to read". Yes, it can be the case that the most recent is the temporary file, but you cannot know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 2-phase commit:

1. Write the new XML to a file with a different name
2. Delete the old file
3. Rename to new file to the old name

This way, there will always be at least one complete file.
If you restart, and the standard name doesn't exist, check for the different name.

Comment: Maybe rename with overwrite instead of delete?

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich: If your filesystem supports that safely.

Comment: What about if the system crashes after `step 1`. You have now two valid files?

Comment: @I4V: Correct; that's why I said _at least one_.  However, you don't (necessarily) know whether the new file is fully written, or if it shut down in the middle of an IO op.

Answer (score 0):

This one could be a life savior but with little more efforts. There should be a separate process which does

- Take backup to its stash automatically whenever the file gets updated.
- It internally maintains two versions in a linked list.
- If the file gets updated, then the latest shall be updated to `HEAD using linkedList.AddFirst()` and the least version pointed by `TAIL` could be removed by `linkedList.RemoveLast()`.
- And of course, it should scan and load the stash about the latest version available in the stash during startup.

In the hard shutdown scenario, when the system starts up next time, this process should check whether the file is valid / corrupted. If corrupted, then restore the latest from `HEAD` and subscribe for `FileChanged` notification using a simple `FileSystemWatcher`.

This approach is well tested.

**Problems seen**

- What if the Hard shutdown happens while updating the `HEAD`? 
  -- Well, there is another version we have it in the stash next to `HEAD`
- What if the Hard shutdown happens while updating the `HEAD` when the stash is empty? -- We know that the file was valid while updating `HEAD`. The process shall try copying again at next startup since it is not corrupted.
- What if the stash is empty and the file has been corrupted? -- This is the death pit and no solution is available for this. But this scenario occurs only when you deploy this recovery process after the file corruption happened.